# ffmpeg using hardware accel runs slower on new PC with better hardware?

Tags: windows-10, video, ffmpeg, performance, nvidia-graphics-card

For several years I've been using a batch file script that utilizes ffmpeg to re-encode videos to h265.  In an older version of ffmpeg (from 2017) I used this line:

`fmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -i input -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 4M -c:a aac output`

I see that with newer versions of ffmpeg the line needs to be modified a little to this:

`ffmpeg -hwaccel nvdec -i input -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 4M -c:a aac output`

The older PC had an i5 CPU with an nVidia GTX 1060 GPU.  The new PC has an i7-9700 with nVidia RTX 2070 SUPER.

On a sample file the older PC processes it at fps=204 and speed=8.5x.  The new PC processes it at fps=130 and speed=5.4x.

I'm guessing there's something further that needs to be modified with my command line but I can't figure out what it is.  I arrived at the command I used after a lot of testing with various settings, but I just can't see why there's such a big difference in processing speed.

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: when i read this , i think you can still use cuda ( https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#CUDANVENCNVDEC )

Comment: @EchoMike444 I tried that earlier and the performance is little changed.  I've tried many settings and nothing I've tried will get the speed much over about 6.4x.  I've even tried at very low quality settings and it doesn't improve anything which is really strange to me.  A couple of years ago I did a lot of testing with ffmpeg to get to the settings I liked every little tweak would results in noticeable improved or worsened encode time.  Now, it seems like no matter what settings I use the encode time is little changed.